# Problems with django app DATABASES setting for heroku deployment

Tags: database, django, postgresql, heroku, waitress

When I change my setting of Database according to the official guide as 
`DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()`
It has 
`NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined` 
when building.

When I change the syntax of database settings to 
`DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}`, 
it has 
`settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.` when opening the app locally. 
and it has 
`Internal Server Error: The server encountered an unexpected internal server error (generated by waitress)` 
when launching from heroku.

Notice, this way worked once. But when i merge my code with my friends, it has problem again. I roughly located it was database problem. So i delete the database on heroku and wanted to sync again. But when I sync the database, it has `Import error: No module named events`.

When I change the setting back to the original way: 
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}`
 
It can work locally(of course), but can't in the heroku, with the error of `Import error: No module named events` too when syncing the database.

PS: 
1, I made sure that Heroku installed all the requirements I need to run the app, especially i triple checked all the files: models, views, urls, etc.
2, I use waitress as the server instead of gunicorn recommended by the Heroku official guide.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable that `dj_database_url` will read.

To set it, run `heroku config: set DATABASE_URL=<your database url>` from your terminal.

Comment: Thanks! but what is my database url? sqlite3? and  I'll write `DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}` in the setting right?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this, as Heroku should set it automatically. Go to the environment settings in the dashboard and check there is one for the database url.